# Spring 3 + Hibernate + JPA + Spring Security 3.1

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, heroku, spring-security

I am currently have trouble with implementing Spring 3 + Hibernate + JPA + Spring Security 3.1
solution.

Here is my web.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns  /javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener> -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my Application Context

```
 <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.muuves.reservosity" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

</bean>

<beans profile="prod">
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url"
            value="#{ 'jdbc:mysql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my security-context

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"
        requires-channel="any" />
</security:http>

<!-- <security:authentication-manager> <security:authentication-provider> 
    <security:user-service> <security:user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" 
    /> </security:user-service> </security:authentication-provider> </security:authentication-manager> -->

<bean id="AccessService"  class="com.muuves.reservosity.service.AccessService" />


<security:authentication-manager> <security:authentication-provider 
    user-service-ref="AccessService"> <security:password-encoder hash="md5" /> 
    </security:authentication-provider> </security:authentication-manager>
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.muuves.reservosity.model.Company_Details;


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Service
public class AccessService implements UserDetailsService{

private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AccessService.class.getName()); 

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)   throws DataAccessException{
    LOG.info("loadUserByUsername");
    LOG.info(username);
    Company_Details domainUser = em.find(Company_Details.class, 1);
    LOG.info(username);
    LOG.info(domainUser.getEmail());
    LOG.info(domainUser.getPassword());
    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User("ahobbsy@gmail.com", "test1234", enabled, accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(1));
}

/**
 * Retrieves a collection of {@link GrantedAuthority} based on a numerical
 * role
 * 
 * @param role
 *            the numerical role
 * @return a collection of {@link GrantedAuthority

 */
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
    return authList;
}

/**
 * Converts a numerical role to an equivalent list of roles
 * 
 * @param role
 *            the numerical role
 * @return list of roles as as a list of {@link String}
 */
public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (role.intValue() == 1) {
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
        roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");

    } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
        roles.add("ROLE_USER");
    }

    return roles;
}

/**
 * Wraps {@link String} roles to {@link SimpleGrantedAuthority} objects
 * 
 * @param roles
 *            {@link String} of roles
 * @return list of granted authorities
 */
public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(
        List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

}

Here is my WEB-INF/persistent.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="dataSource" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org   /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org  /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-hibernate-template</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.27.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Tiles dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0.27.1</version>
                                   <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Don't know why its not working, not sure why I have to create a id for AccessService as I thought it would pick it up by its Annotation!!! Seriously lost with this and have tried so many different examples on the web it would be great if somebody could help me out!!

I have Spring, hibernate and JPA working, i have Spring, hibernate and JPA and hardcoded spring security implementation

```
 <security:authentication-manager> <security:authentication-provider> 
 <security:user-service> <security:user name="mkyong" password="123456"  authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
   </security:user-service> 
 </security:authentication-provider> </security:authentication-manager>
```

I can't link up the implementation of hibernate and spring security

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I use the Spring + Hibernate + JPA + Spring Security in mp application, and I got it to work by breaking the problem down into baby steps. Here is what I would recommend.

- Step 1: Configure JPA and Hiberante with Spring in your app get that working, when you run into problems post those
- Step 2: get spring security working and post specific problems with the configuration when you run into them.

It is a lot easier to answer a specific narrowly focused question than a general question.

Comment: Hi, I have got JPA and hibernate working and got spring security using hard coded Usernames and passwords in the      <security:authentication-manager> <security:authentication-provider> but i can't seem to connection the authentication provider to connect to search my database
    <security:user-service> <security:user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" 
    /> </security:user-service> </security:authentication-provider> </security:authentication-manager>

Comment: I second @ams recommendation, try to break it in pieces. First make it work with the [minimal configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal).

Comment: @elijunior i have that already working, i just can't get it to work with hibernate and spring security with a customuserdetails implementation